# Boolean Property Simplification

Tags: arithmetic, boolean-algebra

I was wondering if there is a term/property/name to describe this simplification:

$$A + \overline{A}B = A + B$$

thank you

Comment: Can you explain your notation?

Comment: hi, yeah the bar just means inverted and the + sign means OR

Comment: And I guess $\bar{A}B$ means $\bar A$ AND $B$ right?

Comment: yeah exactly, thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use $\cup$, $\cap$ notation in my proof instead of $+$,$\cdot$, I hope you don't mind (if you aren't familiarized with them, $\cup$ means OR and $\cap$ means AND). Notice that:
$$A\cup(\bar A\cap B)=(A\cup \bar A)\cap(A\cup B),$$
and $(A\cup \bar A)$ is the universe, so
$$(A\cup\bar A)\cap(A\cup B)=A\cup B,$$
to be said;
$$\boxed{A\cup(\bar A\cap B) = A\cup B}$$

Rewriting it using your notation, it goes like this:

$$A+ \bar AB = (A+\bar A)(A+B)=A+B$$